# Show Kendoui Line Chart on Bootstrap Popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui

I need to show KendoUi Line chart in Bootstrap Popover?

Can anyone suggest me with the references, i searched but not even get a single link to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [popover events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events)

`inserted.bs.popover` is triggered after the popup is shown and inserted in the DOM. At that point there is a content div in the popup with class `popover-content` if you are using the default template.

So create a chart on that DIV in an event handler:

```
$('#myPopover').on('inserted.bs.popover', function ()   {
    CreatePopoverChart();
})

function CreatePopoverChart(){
    // Satter line chart embedded in tooltip
    $(".popover-content").kendoChart({
        chartArea: {
            height: 240,
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "scatterLine"
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40]]
        }],
    });     
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/RpdrpG)**

Comment: Works Perfect... ThanQ very Much for the Support and help.